# Правильно ли так делать в css?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, следующее. В html коде нужным мне спискам `ul li` я не присваиваю классы. В файле стилей стиль прописываю так:

```
.menu ul > li > ul > li {

}
```

В скрипте пишу также:

```
$(".menu > ul > li > a").click(function(e){
```

Правильно ли вообще так делать? Все ли браузеры понимают такие конструкции, в т.ч. и на планшетах и телефонах? Искал такую информацию, но не могу найти, что это такое - `>`, чтобы о них почитать. Благодарю!

Comment: по IE7 включительно работать будет,  > - прямой потомок

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, так делать не правильно.

Это кроссбраузерный вариант и все браузеры будут понимать, что вы имеете ввиду.

Но!

1 - Чтение начинается не слева направо, а справа налево. То есть в такой записи `.menu ul > li > ul > li` сначала перебирает все `li`, потом все `li` c родителем `ul`, потом все `li` с родителями `ul>li` и т. д. При большом количестве элементов на странице такой подход приведет к длительной загрузке.

2 - Такой стиль противоречит методологии `БЕМ`. Что усложняет работу с большими проектами. Конечно вы не обязаны использовать его в своих проектах. Но учитывать возможность хотя бы изменения кода - необходимо.

3 - Такая запись "плодит ошибки", очень легко, особенно в скриптах запутаться во вложенности при такой записи.

Answer (score 1):

`>` - это CSS-селектор, который применяет стиль к дочернему элементу.

> Дочерним называется элемент, который непосредственно располагается
>   внутри родительского элемента. Какой элемент выступает родителем, а
>   какой его потомком легко выяснить с помощью дерева элементов — так
>   называется структура отношений элементов документа между собой (рис.
>   1).
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>   На рис. 1 в удобном виде представлена вложенность элементов и их иерархия. Здесь дочерним элементом по отношению к `<div>` выступает элемент `<p>`. Вместе с тем `<strong>` не является дочерним для элемента `<div>`, поскольку он расположен в контейнере
>
> .

**Синтаксис**

`E > F { Описание правил стиля }`

[Более](http://everstudent.ru/blog/htmlcss/30-css-seletors-to-memorize/) [подробно](https://webref.ru/css/selector/child)